# How to share my site's MP3 audio on facebook and play it on wall it self?

Tags: facebook, audio, mp3, sharing

I want that visitor on my site can share MP3 on FaceBook, the way it play on their wall. I used og:meta tags and used current url as FaceBook sharer path. But no luck. I tried it with JWPlayer. Can anyone suggest me some way please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example is Flowplayer which supports direct embedding via Flowplayer Flash.

Here's the documentation page:

http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/flash/sharing.html

They have a demo which you can try for yourself at:

http://flowplayer.blacktrash.org/fbshare.html

The demo is for a video but I guess you can also do it for audio only.